# custom uitabelviewcell variable returns nil, IBOutlets works fine - Mailcore2

Tags: swift, uitableview, mailcore2, mailcore

i have this problem, no matter what variable "var" i put in the custom uitabelviewcell, it returns nil
while the IBOulets works just fine

tableviewcell.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class tableViewCell: UITableViewCell  {

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewLabelDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewLabelDisplayName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewLabelSubject: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewTextViewInfo: UITextView!
var messageRenderingOperation: MCOIMAPMessageRenderingOperation!

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}
```

tableview.swift

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var cell2: tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseTableViewCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as tableViewCell
            cell2.tag = 0
             let message: MCOIMAPMessage = mailbox?.messages[indexPath.row] as MCOIMAPMessage!
            let uidKey = message.uid
            cell2.tableViewLabelDisplayName?.text = mailbox?.messages[indexPath.row].header.from.displayName
           cell2.tableViewLabelSubject?.text = mailbox?.messages[indexPath.row].header.subject
            println("Got the subject line: \(mailbox?.messages[indexPath.row].header.subject)")

            cell2.messageRenderingOperation = self.imapSession.plainTextBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage(message, folder: "INBOX", stripWhitespace: false)

            cell2.messageRenderingOperation?.start({ (plaintext: String!, error: NSError!) -> Void in   // Crash at this line
                if error != nil{
                    println("ERROR at messageRenderingOperation\(error)")
                }else {
                cell2.tableViewTextViewInfo.text = plaintext
                cell2.messageRenderingOperation = nil
                }
            })

            return cell2

}
```

[image]

it crashes at this line

```
cell2.messageRenderingOperation?.start({ (plaintext: String!, error: NSError!) -> Void in   // Crash at this line
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried this **aswell**

```
class tableviewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
var messageRenderingOperation: MCOIMAPMessageRenderingOperation?
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
self.messageRenderingOperation = imapSession.plainTextBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage(message, folder: "INBOX")
self.messageRenderingOperation.start({ (plaintext: String!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error != nil{
                    println("ERROR at messageRenderingOperation\(error)")
                }else {
                cell2.tableViewTextViewInfo.text = plaintext
                    cell2.messageRenderingOperation = nil
                }
            })
}

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

now if i use

```
var messageRenderingOperation = MCOIMAPMessageRenderingOperation()
```

then it's not nil, but still crashes. i think it's a problem with the "plugin" ?

Comment: Have you tried with code in Obj-C?

Comment: i tried my best to copy the code from the example in the mailcore2 app, same result... i have no idea why it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Since your var is initialized later on you should declare it as optional `var messageRenderingOperation: MCOIMAPMessageRenderingOperation?` and not using force to unwrapping it as you currently declared. Also if you are using storyboard you can initialize it inside awake from nib method

```
class tableViewCell: UITableViewCell  {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewLabelDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewLabelDisplayName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewLabelSubject: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTextViewInfo: UITextView!
    var messageRenderingOperation: MCOIMAPMessageRenderingOperation?

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

   }

   override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.MCOIMAPMessageRenderingOperation = //some initialization
   }
}
```

Comment: ahh, but it still returns nil

Comment: Can you try initializing your var inside UITableViewCell awakeFromNib() method ?

Comment: erhm, how do i do that ? never used awakeFromNib()

Comment: hm this confuses me a little... what sort of initialization should it be ?... i understand that it needs to be initialized but what should be after the =

Comment: You must do exactly what you did in cellForRowAtIndexPath method : = self.imapSession.plainTextBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage(message, folder: "INBOX", stripWhitespace: false)

Comment: No can do... the message variable can't use indexPath.row in the uitabelviewcell 
                 let message: MCOIMAPMessage = mailbox?.messages[indexPath.row] as MCOIMAPMessage!